# How to retrieve user information from Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, android, azure, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm a bit new to Xamarin and Azure Active Directory so please bear with me. I'm having trouble trying to retrieve user information (first name, last name, and picture) from Azure Active Directory. Mind you the emails in the Azure Active Directory are Google accounts.

Every time I try to retrieve it, I only get an error and it requires to me to authenticate AGAIN just to retrieve what I want. Here's my code:

```
 // Use MobileServices Login to authenticate user
 private async Task<bool> AuthenticateUsingMobileServices(Activity activity)
 {
      var success = false;
      try
      {
           // Sign in with Active Directory
           MobileUser = await MobileService.LoginAsync(activity, 
                MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory);
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("you are now logged in - Logged in!");
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine([insert user name here]);
           success = true;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Authentication failed " + ex.ToString());
      }
}
```

I've tried adding this in addition to my already defined ResourceUri and ClientId:

```
 AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(CommonAuthority);
 AuthResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceUri, ClientId, UserCredential);
```

But I'm clueless on what to put for ClientAssertion or UserAssertion.

Answer (score 0):

The steps you have to do is:

1. Authenticate with Azure (you get a User object including token)
2. Place token on every request you're making. This way you authenticate with that specific user.

Check out: https://blog.xamarin.com/authenticate-xamarin-mobile-apps-using-azure-active-directory/